# Отсортировать значение массива "по возрастанию"

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется такой многомерный массив:

```
[112477] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112477
                [1] => 4475124
                [2] => Миасс авто
                [3] => -
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 70868
                        [1] => 70869
                        [2] => 70867
                        [3] => 70865
                        [4] => 70866
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112477
                [1] => 4475125
                [2] => Творчество
                [3] => -
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 70868
                        [1] => 70869
                        [2] => 70867
                        [3] => 70865
                        [4] => 70866
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112477
                [1] => 4475126
                [2] => Культура
                [3] => -
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 70868
                        [1] => 70869
                        [2] => 70867
                        [3] => 70865
                        [4] => 70866
                    )
    )
```

И собственно код PHP:

```
 $search_systems = [];
        foreach($id_temp as $identifier_project)
        {
            $url_phrases  = "https://site.com/api/project/$identifier_project/phrases"; //ФРАЗЫ 1/3
            $get_all_phrases = connectToSite($url_phrases, $token);
            foreach($get_all_phrases as $value_phrase)
            {
                $phrase = $value_phrase['phrase'];
                if($phrase == null){
                    $phrase = 'Данные отсутствуют'; 
                }
                $personal_id = $value_phrase['id'];
                if($personal_id == null){
                    $personal_id = '-//-'; 
                }
                $geo = $value_phrase['is_geo']; 
                if($geo == false){
                    $geo = '-';
                }elseif($geo == true){
                    $geo = '+';
                } 
                $array_phrase[$identifier_project][] = [$identifier_project, $personal_id, $phrase, $geo];
            }
            $url_engines = "https://site.com/api/project/$identifier_project/engines"; //ЗНАЧЕНИЯ ФРАЗ 2/3
            $get_all_engines = connectToSite($url_engines, $token);
            foreach($get_all_engines as $search_system){
                 $search_systems[$identifier_project][] = $search_system['id'];
            }

        }

    foreach($search_systems as $key => $value){
        if(isset($array_phrase[$key])){
             foreach(array_keys($array_phrase[$key]) as $key2){
                  $array_phrase[$key][$key2][] = $value;
             }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($array_phrase); echo "</pre>";
```

Как отсортировать пятый элемент во всех массивах "от 0 до 4", "по возрастанию" "от наименьшего к большему", ключи можно перезаписать.

Выделю конкретный участок где должна быть реализована сортировка

```
foreach($get_all_engines as $search_system){
                 $search_systems[$identifier_project][] = $search_system['id'];
            } 
        }

//здесь должна быть сортировка 
//$search_systems[$identifier_project][] = $search_system['id']; 
///вся работа по поводу сортировки начинается здесь, в значении этого массива присваивается непроизвольные значения
//которые нужно отсортировать по возрастанию.
//нужно сохранить "внешний ключ" $search_systems[$identifier_project][] и отсортировать значения $search_system['id'];

    foreach($search_systems as $key => $value){
        if(isset($array_phrase[$key])){
             foreach(array_keys($array_phrase[$key]) as $key2){
                  $array_phrase[$key][$key2][] = $value;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: вам, очевидно, понадобится цикл по элементам первого уровня и функция `sort()`. В чем проблема то?

Comment: нужно сделать сортировку до цикла foreach($search_systems as $key => $value) т.к он и передаёт данные в основной цикл.

Comment: следовательно мне нужно сохранить "внешний ключ" я про строку $search_systems[$identifier_project][] = $search_system['id'];

Comment: как мне сохранить внешний ключ, и выполнить обычную сортировку?

Comment: $search_systems[$identifier_project] является внешним ключом

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, можно сделать так:

```
foreach ($a[112477] as &$v) {
    asort($v[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто, надо просто было "подумать"

После цикла:

```
foreach($get_all_engines as $search_system){
             $search_systems[$identifier_project][] = $search_system['id'];
        } 
    }
```

Берём значение $search_system и подготовим его для сортировки через foreach

```
foreach ($search_systems as $system ){
        usort($system, function ($a, $b){
            return ($a - $b);
        }); 
        $temper[$identifier_project] = $system;
    }
```

Далее, после того как мы произвели нашу сортировку, кладём результат в новый массив и присвоим "ключ" от внешнего цикла, а "значение" наш готовый отсортированный массив.

И соединяем наш массив

```
foreach($temper as $key => $value){
        if(isset($array_phrase[$key])){
             foreach(array_keys($array_phrase[$key]) as $key2){
                  $array_phrase[$key][$key2][] = $value;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `usort` с таким колбеком аналогичен `asort`.

Comment: мне надо было ключи перезаписать